# Fluent NHibernate: Version column should NOT be used for concurrency

Tags: .net, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

Is there any way of telling fluent NHibernate *not* to use a column called [version] for concurrency checking?  It seems to do this automagically if it finds a column called [version] - and in this case I do not what it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set up an [`IVersionConvention`](http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Conventions/IVersionConvention.htm) and add it to your conventions.

Comment: I don't think that works.  This will allow a Version Property to be mapped to DB Column of a different name. I can not see how to use it to stop a Property/Column with the name Version to not be used for concurrency checking.

Comment: @James: Okay. I should have given details. Write a class that implements `IVersionConvention` and `IVersionAcceptance` (the standard way to implement a convention). Implement `IVersionConventionAcceptance.Accept` as `public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IVersionInspector> criteria) { criteria.Expect(x => false); }` This completely turns off versioning. You can provide the trivial implementation for `IVersionConvention.Apply`.

Comment: That should be `IVersionConventionAcceptance`, not `IVersionAcceptance`.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I appreciate the follow up.  I found another way also (below), but like this way better.

Comment: so, does this mean that the return value of "IsVersion" method in the DefaultAutoMappingConfiguration ultimatly gets delegated down to the Accept method of an IVersionConventionAcceptance convention? Just trying to get my head around how these play together.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have found it is possible to inherit from the DefaultAutoMapConfiguration and override the IsVersion to always return false.  This is effectively turning off versioning.